# Beginner coder: Python list index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, split

I am new to coding and I have extracted data from the column of a table that look like this

```
print(column3)

x; y
x; y
x 
x; y; z
x 
x; y
```

I then split the string by '; '

```
column_elements = column3.split('; ')
print(column_elements)

['x', 'y']
['x', 'y']
['x'] 
['x', 'y', 'z']
['x'] 
['x', 'y']
```

so when I try to print using

```
y = (column_elements[1])
```

I get an error due to not all the lists having a length longer than [0]. I am not 
sure how to get each of the elements from a dataset of varying list lengths.

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: Are you aware that python uses [zero-based indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering)?

Comment: @pault I believe so. Notice he said: _"I get an error due to not all the lists having a length longer **than [0]**"_. Of course, his terminology is off, but I believe he's trying to say you can only accesses the first element of some of his sublist, which implies that the list has a length of one.

Comment: @ChristianDean I also saw that but I wasn't sure. I posted the link because OP said they were a beginner. Didn't mean to come off as sarcastic if that's what you thought- like my profile pic says, I like to think positive.

Comment: @pault It's fine man. I didn't think you were being sarcastic at all :-) I agree, this OP isn't exactly clear. I was just offering my two-cents.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use direct indexing, use `for` over the elements of the list:

```
l = [[0],[1,2,3],[5,2]]

for elem in l:
    for num in elem:
        print(num)
```

or (not as good, not needed, never do this) use `len` to get the length of a inner list (starting at 0 up to len(l)-1 is the index):

```
for idx in range(len(l)):            # len(l) == 3, range(len(l)) == [0,1,2]  
    for idx2 in range(len(l[idx])):     # len of the sublist
        print(l[idx][idx2])
```

Output (for both):

```
0
1
2
3
5
2
```

If you really need the index alongsinde the value, use [enumeration](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and  decomposed index and value:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(l):   # yields you (0,[0]), (1,[1,2,3]), (2,[5,2])
    print(f"Index: {idx} with {val}")
```

Output:

```
Index: 0 with [0]
Index: 1 with [1, 2, 3]
Index: 2 with [5, 2]
```